# I replaced my moped fuel sensor float but its still not working

Tags: gasoline, speedometer

My fuel sensor float stopped working early on, and I've ordered a new float but it still doesn't work. The fuel gauge barely goes up (doesn't go past the "E". Any ideas? Also, my speedometer stopped working as well, but that was much later. Maybe it's connected? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You could start by telling us what *exact* make/model/engine of moped we're dealing with there? Also, you've asked two very separate questions. It'd do well to separate these two. When you do, please include all the information you can to help us help you!

Comment: I have a 2017 or 2018 TaoTao New Speed 50cc. My main question is about the fuel gauge and why it isn't working even after I replaced the gas float

Comment: Did you test the new float sensor before fitting? Has the tank got a decent ground or earth? Or does the sensor have a two or three wire connection (depends if there is a warning light).

Comment: I tested it before I put it in, but it still didnt go past E. The original did the same thing, and this is my second replacement but it's done the same thing. It has 3 sporks on the plug in.